# while i click on login button then fatal error occur Call to a member function execute()

Tags: php, mysql, json

while i click on login button then fatal error:

> Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

in `C:\wamp\www\json\login.php` on line 24 this error occur.

I make a changes but it's not working. `execute()` method not working in proper way.

`login.php` file

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$query = "SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$query_params = array(
':username' => $_POST['username']
);
try {
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
$validated_info = false;
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
$login_ok = true;
}
}
if ($login_ok) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Login successful!";
die(json_encode($response));
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
} else {
?>
<h1>Login</h1> 
<form action="login.php" method="post"> 
Username:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
<br /><br /> 
Password:<br /> 
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
<br /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form> 
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

`config.inc.php` file

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','json') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>
```

`database` :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)
Try to use

```
$stmt->bind_param(...);
```

Comment: Do you try implement what do you need use example link?

Comment: actually i want to login but that execute() function not working